# Get class name of models in collection even if there are no instances in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

Assume I have the following eloquent queries:

```
$collection_one = User::all();
$collection_two = Post::all();
```

When there are users in the collection, I can do the following in order to get the class name of the models in the collection:

$class_name = class_basename($collection_one->first());

However, I cannot figure out how to get the class name for Post, say, when there are no posts in the system.

Comment: Does this work `$class_name = class_basename('\directory\Post');`

Comment: The content of the collection is dynamic, I do not know what type of model I will have in there

Comment: Why do you need the class name?

Comment: I have a method that can accept a collection as an argument and resolve some string based on the name of the model